# cannot find folder xcdatamodeld Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7.1beta

Xcode 7 and 7.1 beta show following error:
[image]

in xcode 6 there is no problem. and i don´t know what i should do.
can someone help me? thank you.
Klaus

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi. No, it won´t work :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here are the steps I used to solve it:

1. Right-click on your project file in Xcode and select 'Show in Finder'.
2. Right-click on your .xcodeproj and select 'Show Package Contents'.
3. Right-click on the project.pbxproj and open it with TextEdit (or any text editor you prefer).
4. Search for "/* Begin XCVersionGroup section */".
5. In my case, I had 2 entries for the .xcdatamodeld file in the XCVersionGroup section. I deleted the first one, which was not accurate (had only one child version, whereas my .xcdatamodeld should have had 3 .xcdatamodel versions), saved the file, and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you Mark, but in my case it is another problem. :-(